# XMPP, WebSocket, and other questions

Tags: android, .net, websocket, xmpp, chat

My aim right now is just to make an Android app that has WhatsApp-like capabilities (not necessarily a clone of WhatsApp; just has similar, perhaps not-so-good features). What's important I guess is group chat, online/offline presence, as well as offline messaging.

Right now I'm aware mostly of the possibility of having a WebSocket server (because I was introduced to it as a *real-time* solution that could open me up to endless possibilities), and I've tested it before--it looks good. However, I'm facing the following issues:

1. I don't know how to manage online/offline presences; do I have to implement that myself? Perhaps the Android client querying the server every 30s if his friends are still connected...
2. How about offline messaging? If a particular person is not connected, the message *will not* be delivered to him. Does the message then need to be stored somewhere (say MSSQL), and then when the person logs in the client will automatically retrieve all offline messages from the server?
3. What about group chats? I'm unsure how WebSocket is able to acheive that, do I have to implement that separately as well? That would mean a lot of biz logic to work on (and a whole lot of room for bugs to appear)...

I'm aware there is a protocol called XMPP (and that it's totally different from WebSocket) but I'm not sure how it relates to my problem. Is XMPP my silver bullet (i.e. are there **.NET** libraries out there that implement most of it there for me?). I've also heard of Comet, but I don't know how it relates at all...

There are so many missing pieces, I thought implementing my chat server/client would be a piece of cake, but apparently not so. Anyone with a l'il experience can give me some feedback?

Answer (score 4):

You can and should be using WebSocket for presence and instant messaging functionality. In fact, instant messaging is the "Hello world" example of the WebSocket world.

Also, the WebSocket standard was designed to support higher level, richer business protocols (which ironically the standard calls sub-protocols). XMPP is one of such protocols, and there are several implementations out there with the exact features you're looking for.

If you'd like to try it out, Kaazing (the company I work for) has a [free download](http://go.kaazing.com/XMPP-Download.html) available. It contains an open source XMPP server (OpenFire), along with the XMPP edition of a pre-configured Kaazing WebSocket Gateway. What Kaazing does is it extends the XMPP protocol to Web clients over WebSocket. It does so transparently, so from the XMPP server's perspective your (browser) client is just another XMPP client.

Another good resource is chapter 4 of [The Definitive Guide to HTML5 WebSocket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430247401) (of which I'm a co-author), titled [Building Instant Messaging and Chat over WebSocket with XMPP](http://books.google.com/books?id=f7Gyuv-tZE0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=definitive%20guide%20to%20html5%20websocket&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7TOEUoi6NciUiALkuYGIDg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=xmpp&f=false). The book also comes with a [free downloadable VM](http://www.apress.com/9781430247401) with open source software pre-installed and configured for your testing. [Here you can see detailed screencasts](http://www.websocket.org/book.html) of the VM - to get an idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but his questions was regarding Android. Which is a mobile device, which can run on Edge, 3G, LTE, or WiFi networks (all with different degrees of battery drain), which have a battery attached to it that determines for how long the user will be able to use the device. Probably the whole server side you're pointing is very nice and correct. But the usage of an always on connection on a mobile device is just bad.

Comment: @Budius a socket dose not drain battery by its self. async Socket dose not drain battery that much.

Answer (score 3):

let's go per parts:

first: Do not use sockets. That means you will need to keep a service running and maintain a connection at all times on each client device. That will drain the battery like crazy and no one will use it. What every-single-one of those apps use including WhatsApp, Hangout, Gmail, Facebook messenger is the Google cloud messaging (GCM) http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html service.

1. maybe you want can send those status change via GCM at the moment they happen, or once the user enters the friend-list screen you do a one-off query with the status, the important thing here is that you will not query every 30 seconds in a mobile device.
2. Yes, if the device is not connected your server have to do the stuff. And I don't believe you'll use SQL, what a lot of companies are doing nowadays is noSQL approaches due to scalability, but it's not my expertise.
3. I'm not sure what you're asking here. You're mixing how you're going to send the data with how your application will treat the data. Those are two completely separate things, learn the difference. Example, Someone could create a group chat that works over WiFi-Direct over UDP (that's **HOW** the data will be sent) but what u do with this data doesn't matter, it could have arrived over Bluetooth that will be the same for the parser/interpreter. It's just data.

Good luck.

Comment: But once the user is running the app on the forefront should I use WebSocket? Or should I rely primarily on GCM and let GCM do the job?

Comment: I would like to know why someone -1 this answer. Makes no sense.

Comment: Good answer, just to add, Whats-app uses XMPP as stated here on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp.

Comment: How can WhatsApp be using GCM? It works on apps that do not have play services.even I am not sure if I should be using GCM for IM or not.

Comment: @harvey_slash they use something else for devices without it (most likely polling every X minutes using the 'AlarmManager'). You can make a simple 'if/else' in code, or use gradle build flavors to build it differently for Google play and other appStores. Important point is that the "other" solution will have harder impact on battery.

Comment: wow, Thats a useful piece of info ! Could you please answer my questions here ?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151587/should-i-use-gcm-for-real-time-communication-between-devices/30151950?noredirect=1#comment48420667_30151950 

But why do answers like http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43970/how-is-whatsapp-able-to-receive-messages-when-not-in-use 
say otherwise ? :/

Comment: @matt hi, I've just re-read this post because of the harvey comment and noticed that you asked the follow up question about foreground, I know I'm a few months delayed, but here it goes. On foreground there's no reason to not use WebSocket if you have the need for "real time" flow, but you should just be sure to not leave this connection open after the app goes to background.

Comment: @harvey_slash apparently there's been some confusion on my answer and your question. Most of my answer was focusing on while the app is in background, that was the focus because the question was focused in online/offline presence and constant polling. After the app is in foreground I don't think GCM is the way to go. Also `android.stackexchange` answer is incorrect/outdated. I've just downloaded ManifestViewer from GPlay and I can guarantee you that WhatsApp have the `c2dm` permissions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77520/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-budius).